# Recover database until cancel?

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2, rman

I'm trying to use the command `restore database until cancel`, but I'm getting the following erro:

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "cancel": expecting one of: "scn, sequence, time"
RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 24 file: standard input
```

Is this command deprecated?

My Oracle database version is the 11g R2

Answer (score 3):

`recover database until cancel` is for user managed recovery in `SQL*Plus`.

It is not a valid syntax in RMAN.

Answer (score 2):

It's "recover", not "restore":

```
recover database until cancel;
```

See here: http://dba-oracle.com/bk_recover_database_until_cancel_tips.htm